# Similarities between "gegen" and "gegenüber"

Tags: preposition, dative, accusative

Are there any instances where "gegen" and "gegenüber" mean the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

I know of one instance where they can be used more or less interchangably:

"Eine Forderung gegen jemanden haben" is an idiomatic way of saying "to have a claim against someone."

"Eine Forderung gegenüber jemandem haben" is slightly less idiomatic, but still correct German.

But this is just a coincidence: It's the only instance I can think of where "gegen" is the more or less meaningless preposition associated with a noun (rather than, say, a meaningful preposition denoting a direction or something like that), and "gegenüber" can pretty much always stand in as that sort of preposition, especially when the most idiomatic usage is mostly known to professionals.

I should also add that I'm not convinced that they "mean the same thing" here, since they are both more or less meaningless in this context. (Is nothing a thing? Do two things that mean nothing mean the same thing?)

Comment: Hätte meinen gelöschten Post erst kommentieren ("Danke, sgf, aber Dein Gegenbeispiel widerlegt mich."), dann löschen sollen. :)

Comment: @userunknown Wie gesagt, ich bin mir gar nicht so sicher, wie sehr ich hier widerlege. Kann man hier wirklich von einer eigenen Bedeutung von "gegen" und "gegenüber" sprechen? Sollte man nicht eher sagen, dass "gegen" hier die Funktion hat, das Objekt der Forderungen zu bezeichnen, und "gegenüber" eine generelle Funktion hat, den zweiten Teil einer Relation zu bezeichnen?

Comment: @userunknown Aber das ist das Tückische an Allaussagen, dass ein einziges (zufälliges) Gegenbeispiel reicht, um sie zu widerlegen.

Comment: Das war mir bewusst, als ich geantwortet habe, aber mir ist kein Beispiel eingefallen und ich dachte, so ein Schuss aus der Hüfte provoziert sicher manche, mich zu widerlegen. :)

Comment: @userunknown :) Tatsächlich hätte ich mir sonst womöglich gar nicht die Mühe gemacht.